# is it possible not to repeat inline conditions? Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider such a header of multistep form:

```
<ul class="steps-selector">
    <li>
        <a ng-class="{'active':isCurrentStep(0)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep(0)">intro</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-class="{'active':isCurrentStep(1)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep(1)">situation</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-class="{'active':isCurrentStep(2)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep(2)">prognosis</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Those steps surely have different names but is the `ng-class="{'active':isCurrentStep(2)}"`/`ng-click` reappearing n times normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-repeat` to loop over your object see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">
    <a ng-class="{'active':isCurrentStep($index)}" ng-click="setCurrentStep($index)">intro</a>
</li>
```

Comment: got it, so I can reference scope steps array in ng-repeat!